# open statement in a recursive subroutine

Tags: fortran90

I wanted to write my results into a file which is produced in a recursive subroutine. And I also wanted to assign the data(read) in the file to an array in my main program in fortran90.

```
program permutations
  implicit none

  call generate (position_min)

  open(unit=20, file="a.dat", status="old")
  do i=1,720
     read(20,*)(G(i,j),j=1,6)
  end do
contains
 recursive subroutine generate (position)
   implicit none
   integer, intent (in) :: position
   integer :: value

   if (position > position_max) then
     open(unit=20, file="a.dat", status="unknown")
     write (20, *) permutation
   else
     call generate(position+1)
   end if

 end subroutine generate
end program permutations
```

This program gives me the following runtime error.

```
At line 19 of file p2.f90 (unit = 20, file = 'a.dat')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Obviously your file is not 720 lines long with 6 integers per line, it is smaller than that. Use your favorite text editor and see how many lines there really are (and if all 6 integers are there) and then edit your code accordingly.

Comment: You haven't closed unit 20 after writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is primarily my comment to the question. If you look at your code (neglecting the undeclared variable issue), in particular the `if`-statement of the recursive subroutine, you should note that you have

```
if (position > position_max) then
  open(unit=20, file="a.dat", status="unknown")
  write (20, *) permutation
else
  call generate(position+1)
end if
```

that is, you are **only** writing to file **if** `position > position_max`. Satisfying this condition writes **one** line to `a.dat` and then completes **all** of the previous `if` statements. What you probably meant to have was it writing to file *each* time through the recursive loop; to do that, you would want something like

```
open(20,file="a.dat",status="unknown")
write(20,*) permutation
close(20)
if(position > position_max) then
   return
else
   call generate(position+1)
endif
```

In running this, I found I was getting 2 extra lines (due to writing at `position=position_min` and at `position=position_max`). You probably could tweak that to get exactly 720, but I think that this part is irrelevant because you can change your `read` loop to the following

```
i=1
do
   read(20,*,iostat=ierr) G(i,:)
   if(ierr/=0) exit
   i = i+1
enddo
```

A normal read returns an `iostat` of 0 and an end-of-file returns -1, so as long as you can read you will continue the loop and break when the EOF is found.

After fixing up the undeclared variables, adding the `close(20)` statement, and adjusting as I commented above, I had no problems writing and reading in the recursive subroutine.